# Android: How to change divide the screen in 3 equal buttons

Tags: android, button, screen

I have 3 buttons in a layout. What I want to do is increase the size of the buttons so they fill the entire screen. How can I do that in the xml file?

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: show some sample UI that you want.

Comment: I was thinking maybe making the height of the buttons dependand on the screen, ie. android:layout_height="(screen size/3)" you know what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You need weightSum

Comment: buttons should be vertically and if you are using `weight` then you should to give `height=0dip` if `vertical` and `width=0dip` if horizontal. otherwise `weight` has no affect.

Comment: Strickly speaking you DO NOT NEED `weightSum`. You can achieve the same just by assigning weights, without assigning a weight sum. My guess is that Android calculates the weight sum on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `weight` property of a `LinearLayout`. I'm gonna make a guess and assume you want the buttons in a vertical layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `Buttons` will always fill the screen and you can play with the weight value to modify their height

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the buttons inside a LinearLayout and use weight:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="3">
<Button 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button 
     android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Comment: they want buttons vertically.

Comment: This or Carlos J's answer are more correct than the selected answer.